# Find the smallest elements in a matrix and check if they already exist

Tags: java, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix which is two dimensional. This has exactly four rows and columns. I now want to create a offer, which contains four elements.
A offer can be calculated as follows: `Offer1 = Matrix_ce + Matrix_ef + Matrix_fg = (c, e, f, g)`. The following cost matrix can be seen below. I am now looking for an offer which is the lowest cost. An offer may now contain unequal numbers, i.e. it may not contain the same number. Formally said  `c ≠ e ≠ f ≠ g`

```
// Note: It looks like every row is the same, but only in this example.
// I have another matrix where all rows are different.
Matrix =  [[14 16 18 20]
          [14 16 18 20]
          [14 16 18 20]
          [14 16 18 20]]
```

Calculation example:

If I now consider the offer, which is `[1 2 3 4]`, If we now apply the offer to the `Matrix` the procedure is as follows to calculate the cost.

For A:

- First I go to row 1 and select the second element there (in this case the number 2 in the cost matrix A).
- Then in row 2, column 3 (value: 7)
- Then in row 3, column 4 (value: 12)

So the costs for the Offer are `Offer = 16 + 18 + 20 = 54`. These are high, so look for the smallest possible order. For example, a better offer would be `Offer = [4 1 2 3] =  14 + 16 +18 = 48`.

[Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grc2S.png) and
[Matrix with explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQeKH.png)

I want to find the I would like to find the items with the small total amount.

How can I now create a offer as low as possible? I have started to create two loops and in this loop always the smallest elements in the matrix should be found, thereby the following conditions must not be violated. For example: `Offer1 = Matrix_ce + Matrix_ef + Matrix_fg = (c, e, f, g), c ≠ e ≠ f ≠ g`. Such a solution with [1 1 1 1] or [1 2 3 1], ... would not be correct. Does anyone have an idea how to calculate this? There are several solutions, and therefore several offers. However, I am only looking for one.

```
int[][] matrix = new int[][]{[14,16,18,20],
                             [14,16,18,20],
                             [14,16,18,20],
                             [14,16,18,20]}
int[] elements = new int[matrix.length];
int[] offer = new int[matrix.length];
for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {

  for(int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; i++) {
     // What is the best way to find the smallest elements?
     Check that values are not duplicated, if the value is already present, skip it.
     //if(Arrays.asList(elements).contains(matrix[i][j])) {
     //  continue;
     //}

  }

}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(offer));
```

Comment: you can use bactracing (recursion) as is used in [this (n queens problem)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-for-n-queen-problem-backtracking-3/#:~:text=The%20N%20Queen%20is%20the,two%20queens%20attack%20each%20other.&text=The%20expected%20output%20is%20a,for%20above%204%20queen%20solution.)

Answer (score 0):

```
int min = matrix[0];
int lowestIndex = 0;
for(int j = 1; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
    if(matrix[I][j] < min){
        lowestIndex = j;
        min = matrix[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just do not quite understand how to get to the solution with it?

Comment: do you just want to find the smallest element or elements in a 2d array?